# Function that takes either 1 parameter xor the other

Tags: python, function, parameters, parameter-passing, xor

I want to write a python function that must take either parameter1 or parameter2, but not both and not 0.

i.e. I want to have a function something like

```
def fun(param1 = None, param2 = None):
  if all(p is None for p in {param1, param2}):
    raise ValueError('Expected either param1 xor param2')

  if both(param1 and param2):
    raise ValueError('Expected either param1 xor param2')
```

Where param1 and param2 do not have the same properties.

How could I do this?

Comment: When you can't cope with a function's parameter list - it's a sign to decompose/separate the function

Comment: can it take a third parameter `param3`?

Comment: If you can only have one or the other, why not just have 1 parameter for either case instead?

Comment: What exactly distinguishes `param1` from `param2`? A simple way to ensure that you get exactly one argument is to define exactly one parameter with no default value.

Comment: Let's back up a moment: _why_ do you want this? Because there is no reason to need this at the function level, so it's entirely likely you're trying to do something for which there's a better way to do it (especially given that this is Python).

Answer (score 0):

My take on the problem:

```
def fun(*args):
    if len(set(i for i, arg in enumerate(args) if arg is not None)) != 1:
        # raise ValueError
        print('Error')
        return
    param1, param2 = args
    print(param1, param2)

fun(1, 1)
fun(1, None)
fun(None, 2)
fun(None, None)
```

Prints:

```
Error
1 None
None 2
Error
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to ask 2 questions at once.

- To have multiple different inputs
- To get exclusive or

The first part is obtained by using the wildcard argument and adding the possible keyword argument behind it

```
def fun(*args, arg1=None, arg2=None): 
    print(arg1, arg2)
```

Now I can call the function with any of the two keyword arguments that I want, do please note that I have to define the keyword arguments arg1 and arg2 if I want to add **any** values to them.

E.g.:

```
fun()                  # None None
fun(arg1=1)            # 1 None
fun(arg2=2)            # None 2
fun(arg1=3, arg2=4)    # 3, 4

# Calls without keyword are stored inside args
fun(1)                 # None None
```

For the second part, we can unpack the xor statement to the original form '(a and not b) or (not a and b)'

Then we will end up with the following code and test.

```
def fun(*args, arg1=None, arg2=None):
    print(arg1, arg2)
    if (arg1 and not arg2) or (not arg1 and arg2):
        print(arg1, arg2)
        return
    return "Error"

fun()                  # None None
fun(1)                 # None None
fun(arg1=1)            # 1 None
fun(arg2=2)            # None 2
fun(arg1=3, arg2=4)    # 3 4
```

I do hereby assume that arg1 and arg2 contain some values that do not convert to the boolean False. If that is the case, you need to add the is not None check to prevent errors.

Answer (score 0):

This code gets parameters like XOR

```
def fun(param1=None, param2=None):
  if (not param1) == (not param2):
    raise ValueError('Expected either param1 xor param2')
```

result:

```
fun() => Error
fun(param1="value") => OK
fun(param2="value") => OK
fun(param1="value", param2="value") => Error
```